# Finding Direct3D 12 using CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

So I've been trying to learn CMake and use it with C++. I'd like to have a go at creating a portable game engine which uses **Direct3D 12** on Windows.

Currently, I have the following `CMakeLists.txt` for my project:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)

project(PsychoEngineCore)

set(SRCS_CXX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/dir_src.cmake)

set(LIB_TYPE "STATIC" CACHE STRING "Static or Dynamic Linking")

if(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL GNU OR
${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL Clang)
    set(warnings "-Wall -Wextra -Werror")
elseif(${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID} STREQUAL MSVC)
    set(warnings "/W4 /WX /EHsc")
endif()

if(NOT CONFIGURED_ONCE)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${warnings}"
        CACHE STRING "Flags used by the compiler during all build types." FORCE)
endif()

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

# Do we want static libraries?
# When STATIC_LINKING is TRUE, then cmake looks for binaries ending in ".a".
# THIS IS FOR LINUX ONLY!
if(LIB_TYPE EQUAL STATIC)
    if (UNIX AND NOT APPLE)
        set(CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES(".a"))
    endif(UNIX AND NOT APPLE)

    set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
    set_target_properties(surface PROPERTIES LINK_SEARCH_END_STATIC 1)
endif(LIB_TYPE EQUAL STATIC)

include_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)
include(GenerateExportHeader)
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} ${LIB_TYPE} ${SRCS_CXX})
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(
    ${PROJECT_NAME}
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME PE_API
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Engine/API/${PROJECT_NAME}Export.hpp
    DEPRECATED_MACRO_NAME PE_API_DEP
    STATIC_DEFINE PE_STATIC
)
```

Currently I have my `d3d12.lib` file in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Libs\10.0.16299.0\um\x64
```

Is there a way to keep the path dynamic and preferably "update" if a newer version is available on said system?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please give a [mcve] of where the library is currently embedded in your code? The shown example doesn't seem to reference the Direct3D library. Generally speaking, just add a `target_link_libraries((${PROJECT_NAME} d3d12.lib)` call. The Windows SDK (where [the Direct3D SDK is now part of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx)) is in the standard search paths of the linker for libraries. And I don't think that upgrading to a newer (yet unknown) API version automatically is a good idea. Windows does also support "older" API versions.

Comment: @Florian So, so long as the **Direct3D SDK** is within my filepath (Which as you say is standard anyway) Then CMake should in theory find what ever version is present on the compilers PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer*

Generally speaking, just add a

```
target_link_libraries((${PROJECT_NAME} d3d12.lib)
```

The Windows SDK (where [the Direct3D SDK is now part of](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275(v=vs.85).aspx)) is in the standard search paths e.g. of the linker for libraries. So it's found automatically by the MSVC compiler and linker.

And I don't think that upgrading to a newer (yet unknown) API version automatically is a good idea. You're writing your program for a specific API version.

**Working Example**

Here is a minimal working example (Tested VS2017 15.5.5, CMake 3.9.0):

```py
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

project(Direct3DExample)

find_package(Git REQUIRED)

set(_path "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/Samples/Desktop/D3D12HelloWorld/src/HelloTriangle")
if (NOT EXISTS "${_path}")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND "${GIT_EXECUTABLE}" clone https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples.git
    )
endif()

file(GLOB _files "${_path}/*")
list(APPEND _shader ${_files})
list(FILTER _files EXCLUDE REGEX "\\.vcxproj|\\.hlsl")
list(FILTER _shader INCLUDE REGEX "\\.hlsl")

get_filename_component(_name "${_path}" NAME)

add_executable(${_name} WIN32 ${_files})
target_compile_definitions(${_name} PRIVATE "UNICODE" "_UNICODE")
target_link_libraries(${_name} PRIVATE "d3d12.lib" "dxgi.lib" "d3dcompiler.lib")

add_custom_command(
    TARGET ${_name}
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -E copy ${_shader} $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${_name}>
)
```

If you need more (compilers/linkers that are not finding the Windows SDK automatically), you may want to look the following `find_package()` config code:

- https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXShaderCompiler/blob/master/cmake/modules/FindD3D12.cmake

Comment: I changed the line set(_path "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Dire...
to set(_path "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Dire.., and it works. GOOD JOB Florian!

Comment: Ah, the `d3dcompiler` was really helpful. I was trying to compile some HLSL shaders and kept getting an undefined reference until I linked that library.