# Cannot find D3DX11.lib using CMake

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, cmake, nmake

I'm learning how to use CMake by making a basic CMakeLists.txt file without macros and targetting x86 only

However, the project requires d3dx11.lib and I cannot seem to get it to build, it fails at the linker stage

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file.

Maybe something is out of order or written incorrectly.

The path for the library exists and the library is there: 
`C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK/Lib/x86`

The same project also builds with Visual Studio without issues, but I am trying to build with NMake

Im assuming that since its failing at the linker stage, its finding all the headers correctly,

Thanks

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.0)

#set(CMAKE_GENERATOR "NMake Makefiles" CACHE INTERNAL "" FORCE)

project(TestProject CXX)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DUNICODE)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_UNICODE)

ADD_DEFINITIONS(-D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE)

#set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -G"NMake Makefiles")

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_executable(TestProject 
    Source/main.cpp
    )


set_target_properties (${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES
    CXX_STANDARD 17
    CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED TRUE
    CXX_EXTENSIONS FALSE
    )

#set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "-m64" LINK_FLAGS "-m64")

FIND_PATH(DX_INCLUDE_PATH d3d11.h
    PATHS
    "$ENV{DXSDK_DIR}/Include"
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK/Include"
    DOC "The directory where D3D11.h resides")

find_library(D3D11_LIBRARY d3d11.lib
    PATHS
    "$ENV{DXSDK_DIR}/Lib/x86"
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK/Lib/x86"
    DOC "The directory where d3d11.lib resides")

find_library(D3DX11_LIBRARY d3dx11.lib
    PATHS
    "$ENV{DXSDK_DIR}/Lib/x86"
    "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK/Lib/x86"
    DOC "The directory where d3dx11.lib resides")


set (D3D11_FOUND "YES")
set (D3D11_LIBRARIES ${D3D11_LIB})
mark_as_advanced (D3D11_INCLUDE_PATH D3D11_LIB)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE d3dx11.lib)
```

This is the generated CMakeCache

```
# This is the CMakeCache file.
# For build in directory: e:/Projects/TestProject/Debug
# It was generated by CMake: C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
# You can edit this file to change values found and used by cmake.
# If you do not want to change any of the values, simply exit the editor.
# If you do want to change a value, simply edit, save, and exit the editor.
# The syntax for the file is as follows:
# KEY:TYPE=VALUE
# KEY is the name of a variable in the cache.
# TYPE is a hint to GUIs for the type of VALUE, DO NOT EDIT TYPE!.
# VALUE is the current value for the KEY.

########################
# EXTERNAL cache entries
########################

//Choose the type of build, options are: None Debug Release RelWithDebInfo
// MinSizeRel ...
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug

//Enable/Disable color output during build.
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON

//CXX compiler
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx86/x86/cl.exe

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=/DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/MDd /Zi /Ob0 /Od /RTC1

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/MD /O1 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/MD /O2 /Ob2 /DNDEBUG

//Flags used by the CXX compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /DNDEBUG

//Libraries linked by default with all C++ applications.
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES:STRING=kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib

//Flags used by the linker during all build types.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86

//Flags used by the linker during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Install path prefix, prepended onto install directories.
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/SimManager

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Enterprise/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.25.28610/bin/Hostx86/x86/link.exe

//Program used to build from makefiles.
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:STRING=nmake

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// all build types.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of modules during
// RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Path to a program.
CMAKE_MT:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.18362.0/x86/mt.exe

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_DESCRIPTION:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_HOMEPAGE_URL:STATIC=

//Value Computed by CMake
CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME:STATIC=SimManager

//RC compiler
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/bin/10.0.18362.0/x86/rc.exe

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during all build types.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS:STRING=-DWIN32

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-D_DEBUG

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags for Windows Resource Compiler during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=/INCREMENTAL:NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of shared libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=/debug /INCREMENTAL

//If set, runtime paths are not added when installing shared libraries,
// but are added when building.
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//If set, runtime paths are not added when using shared libraries.
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=NO

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during all build types.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=/machine:X86

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during DEBUG builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during MINSIZEREL builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELEASE builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=

//Flags used by the linker during the creation of static libraries
// during RELWITHDEBINFO builds.
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=

//If this value is on, makefiles will be generated without the
// .SILENT directive, and all commands will be echoed to the console
// during the make.  This is useful for debugging only. With Visual
// Studio IDE projects all commands are done without /nologo.
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=FALSE

//Path to the legacy d3d11.lib file
D3D11_LIB:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK/Lib/x86/d3d11.lib

//The directory where d3d11.lib resides
D3D11_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Lib/10.0.18362.0/um/x86/d3d11.lib

//Path to the legacy d3dx11.lib file
D3DX11_LIB:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK/Lib/x86/d3dx11.lib

//The directory where d3dx11.lib resides
D3DX11_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK/Lib/x86/d3dx11.lib

//Path to the legacy dxerr11x.lib file
DXERR11_LIB:FILEPATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft DirectX SDK/Lib/x86/DxErr.lib

//The directory where D3D11.h resides
DX_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=C:/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/10/Include/10.0.18362.0/um

//Value Computed by CMake
SimManager_BINARY_DIR:STATIC=E:/Projects/temp/HWVal/HololensET/SimManager/Debug

//Value Computed by CMake
SimManager_SOURCE_DIR:STATIC=E:/Projects/temp/HWVal/HololensET/SimManager


########################
# INTERNAL cache entries
########################

//This is the directory where this CMakeCache.txt was created
CMAKE_CACHEFILE_DIR:INTERNAL=e:/Projects/TestProject/Debug
//Major version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MAJOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=3
//Minor version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_MINOR_VERSION:INTERNAL=17
//Patch version of cmake used to create the current loaded cache
CMAKE_CACHE_PATCH_VERSION:INTERNAL=0
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake.exe
//Path to cpack program executable.
CMAKE_CPACK_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cpack.exe
//Path to ctest program executable.
CMAKE_CTEST_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/ctest.exe
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES
CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_LIBRARIES-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to cache edit program executable.
CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/bin/cmake-gui.exe
//Executable file format
CMAKE_EXECUTABLE_FORMAT:INTERNAL=Unknown
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Name of external makefile project generator.
CMAKE_EXTRA_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator.
CMAKE_GENERATOR:INTERNAL=NMake Makefiles
//Generator instance identifier.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator platform.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_PLATFORM:INTERNAL=
//Name of generator toolset.
CMAKE_GENERATOR_TOOLSET:INTERNAL=
//Source directory with the top level CMakeLists.txt file for this
// project
CMAKE_HOME_DIRECTORY:INTERNAL=E:/Projects/TestProject/
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_LINKER
CMAKE_LINKER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_MT
CMAKE_MT-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//number of local generators
CMAKE_NUMBER_OF_MAKEFILES:INTERNAL=1
//Platform information initialized
CMAKE_PLATFORM_INFO_INITIALIZED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_COMPILER
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
CMAKE_RC_COMPILER_WORKS:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_RC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//Path to CMake installation.
CMAKE_ROOT:INTERNAL=C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.17
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
//ADVANCED property for variable: D3D11_LIB
D3D11_LIB-ADVANCED:INTERNAL=1
```

The build error Im getting is:

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dx11.lib'`

Comment: You forgot to include error message into the question post. BTW, if you build this for x86, then why `machine:X64` flags? Otherwise, how do you expect x64 program to use x86 library `d3dx11.lib`?

Comment: And why do you use `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -G"NMake Makefiles")` again and again even knowing it doesn't work? Or even cause a harm...

Comment: Where do you see x64 flags? I switched to building 32 bit, 64 bit was causing too many issues right now

Comment: I mean the line `set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS machine:X64)` and following 2 ones in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

Comment: My mistake, I removed them, cleared Debug folder, still gettign the same error : `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'd3dx11.lib'`

Answer (score 1):

In case it was building using the `Visual Studio`, try to set the build generator by starting cmake:

```
cmake -GNMake path_of_your_root_cmakelists_file
```

You couldn't set the generator within the root `CMakeLists.txt` as it is than already too late for cmake (it needs to start the generator before it can resolve those sets).

You could also check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269833/cmake-selecting-a-generator-within-cmakelists-txt).

for the second problem: not finding the library, you could check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48955632/finding-direct3d-12-using-cmake)
and evtl. propagate your DirectX installation path, by calling:

```
cmake -GNMake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/your/installation_path .
```

this should do the trick.

Comment: Not building visual studio, I learned that I can't set generator in the CMakeLists.txt, but I still have the `set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS -G"NMake Makefiles")` line there, I will comment out